# Excel 2016 how to create concurrent data analysis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, spss, sentinel

My data looks similar to the example below:

Day 1

a
b
c

day 2

a
b
c
a

day 3

a
x
y
a
b
c
a

day 4

a
a
b
b
x
y
a
a
b

day 5

(no info)

I need to create a data analysis showing counts of the concurrent "info" being used each day. The data analysis I am seeking to create, could look something like the example below:

Day 1
concurrent info: 1 a, 1 b, 1 c

Day 2
concurrent info: 2 a, 1 b, 1 c

Day 3
concurrent info: 3 a, 1 b, 1 c, 1 x, 1 y

Day 4
concurrent info: 4 a, 3 b, 1 x, 1 y

Day 5
concurrent info: (blank)

The days do not begin or end upon predictable rows. What can I do to properly collect the information, and keep it labelled within the days?

Answer (score 0):

Not identical to but to me *something like*:

[image: SO38927337 example]

This merely applies a PT as shown to your source data after your second column's blanks have been filled in. A quick way to fill them in is to select Column B, Go To Special..., Blanks, `=`, `↑`, `Ctr`+`Enter`.

If data is to be added each day the day number for it would need to be filled down and the PT refreshed. The `(blank)`s arise from missing rows so there is no need to extend the PT source data range each day, only Refresh.